# How to split a string with delimited as pipe (which is not inside double quotes

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, delimiter

I have a string like below, which is pipe separated. it has double quotes around string (ex: "ANI").

How do I split this with pipe delimiter (which are not inside double quotes) ?

```
511186|"ANI"|"ABCD-102091474|E|EFG"||"2013-07-20 13:47:19.556"
```

And splitted values shoule be like below:

```
511186
"ANI"
"ABCD-102091474|E|EFG"

"2013-07-20 13:47:19.556"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

The answer that I accepted, did not work for those strings which has double quotes inside. Any idea, what should be the issue ?

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 string regexFormat = string.Format(@"(?:^|\{0})(""[^""]*""|[^\{0}]*)", '|');
string[] result = Regex.Matches("111001103|\"E\"|\"BBB\"|\"XXX\"|||10000009|153086649|\"BCTV\"|\"REV\"|||1.00000000|||||\"ABC-BT AD\"|\"\"\"ABC - BT\"\" AD\"|||\"N\"||\"N\"|||\"N\"||\"N",regexFormat)
  .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
  foreach(var i in result)
  Console.WriteLine(i)
```

Comment: Tag your question with regex and I am sure someone will come in and probably be able to give you one to split the string the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match the items in the string:

```
string[] result = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?:^|\|)(""[^""]*""|[^|]*)")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Explanation:

```
(?:       A non-capturing group
^|\|      Matches start of string or a pipe character
)         End of group
(         Capturing group
"[^"]*"   Zero or more non-quotes surrounded by quotes
|         Or
[^|]*     Zero or more non-pipes
)         End of group
```

Comment: If the delimiter was comma, can I use this -> "(?:^,\,)(""[^""]*""|[^,]*)"

Comment: @Relativity: No, the first pipe is the or operator so you should keep that, and you don't have to escape the comma: `@"(?:^|,)(""[^""]*""|[^,]*)"`.

Comment: If we escape comma, is that fine? ...because I am building a common expression...where I cna use string.format to make it dynamic.  string regexFormat = string.Format(@"(?:^|\{0})(""[^""]*""|[^{0}]*)", delim);

Comment: @Relativity: Yes, that's fine. To make it work with any character you should escape the last one also: `string regexFormat = string.Format(@"(?:^|\{0})(""[^""]*""|[^\{0}]*)", delim);`.

Comment: Could you please have a look at edit. For those kind of string (those with double quotes inside data - the regex is not working. Thanks.

Comment: @Relativity: I didn't include any escaped quotation marks, as there is not a single way to do that. To match quotation marks escaped in that way you would use `(?:""|[^"])*` in the quoted value, so: `@"(?:^|\|)(""(?:""""|[^""])*""|[^|]*)"`. Note that it will only match the values, if you want to unescape the value you have to do that with a replace after matching them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
public List<string> Parse(string str)
{
    var parts = str.Split(new[] {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        string part = parts[i];

        if (IsPartStart(part))
        {
            List<string> sub_parts = new List<string>();

            do
            {
                sub_parts.Add(part);
                i++;
                part = parts[i];
            } while (!IsPartEnd(part));

            sub_parts.Add(part);

            part = string.Join("|", sub_parts);
        }

        result.Add(part);
    }

    return result;

}

private bool IsPartStart(string part)
{
    return (part.StartsWith("\"") && !part.EndsWith("\"")) ;
}

private bool IsPartEnd(string part)
{
    return (!part.StartsWith("\"") && part.EndsWith("\""));
}
```

This works by splitting everything, and it then joins some of the parts that needs joining by searching for parts that starts with `"` and corresponding parts that ends with `"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Split("|", inputString);
```

...will give you the individual parts, but will fail if any of the parts have a pipe separator in them.

If it's a CSV file, following all the usual CSV rules about character-escaping, etc. (but using a pipe symbol instead of comma), then you should look at using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), a NuGet package designed for reading and writing CSV files. It does all the hard work, and deals with all the corner cases that you'd otherwise have to do yourself.

Comment: Oops! I didn't notice that your example input already had pipe symbols in some of the parts, sorry. Still, check out CsvHelper.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it. It's fairly simple and I think you'll find it's very fast as well. I haven't run any tests, but I'm pretty confident that it's faster than regular expressions.

```
IEnumerable<string> Parse(string s)
{
    int pos = 0;

    while (pos < s.Length)
    {
        char endChar = '|';

        // Test for quoted value
        if (s[pos] == '"')
        {
            pos++;
            endChar = '"';
        }

        // Extract this value
        int newPos = s.IndexOf(endChar, pos);
        if (newPos < 0)
            newPos = s.Length;
        yield return s.Substring(pos, newPos - pos);

        // Move to start of next value
        pos = newPos + 1;
        if (pos < s.Length && s[pos] == '|')
            pos++;
    }
}
```